# How to convert session to double in C# Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, double, type-conversion

I have two different forms and I created session to pass values between forms. In the first form I have textbox and input is decimal value;

```
Session["preprandial"] = txtFasting.Text;
```

Then, in the second form I need to convert it to double;

```
double preprandial = Convert.ToDouble(Session["preprandial"]);
```

When I use this code the decimal number is not representing correctly. For example; if the value is equal to 126.5 it will be 1265.0 after conversion. So, I tried to use some parse function but I can not make it. How can I convert it to double?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have problems with Culture, for example you use comma as separator, and your program expects dot(or vice versa):

So i suggest you to use `TryParse`, specify `NumberStyles`, IFormatProvider, depending on you needs, for example:

```
  double r;
  double.TryParse(Session["preprandial"].ToString(), NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out r);
```

Also you should check that object in Session is not not.

Usually i use next Extension method for double conversion:

```
    public static double ToDouble(this object o)
    {
        double d;
        if (!Double.TryParse((o ?? "").ToString().Replace(",", "."), NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out d))
            throw new FormatException(String.Format("Can't parse {0} to double", o));
        return d;
    }
```

Comment: Which number style should I use instead of Any? There are a lot of number styles into it.

Comment: I usually use Any, but that's enum and you might want to use something else, depending on your needs.

Comment: I defined a string and assigned it to 12,1. Then I tried TryParse, it worked and converted to 12.1. So, your second code will probably work.